# Interface orientation doesn't work in landscape (or upside-down depending the case)

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, in `Deployment Info` of my target, I checked all the device orientations. When I run my app, all of them are working except upside-down.

I don't understand why.

Then on my main viewController I added this:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue |
            UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue |
            UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue |
            UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
}
```

Now it works in portrait and portrait upside-down but it doesn't work in landscape.

Any idea why?

Thanks